# How can I use implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I don't understand how to find $y' = x^2y - xy^2 + x^2 + y^2 = 0$?

The book says the next step is $D_x x^2y - D_x xy^2 + D_x(x^2)  + D_x(y^2) = 0$.

After that, it's:

$$x^2 y' + yD_x(x^2) - xD_x(y^2) - y^2 D_x(x^2) + 2x+ 2yy' = 0$$

How did it get from the first line to the next? What does $y'$ mean? What does $D_x$ mean? How did $D_x$ interact with the line to produce the terms in the second?

Comment: Please present the complete problem because this is incomprehensible.

Comment: I think $Dx(f(x))$ is the same as $\frac{df}{dx}$. From the first line to the second, they simply took the derivative with respect to x and from the second line to the third, they used product rule and chain rule.

Comment: Are you saying that you are given $x^2y-xy^2+x^2+y^2=0$ and you are to find $y'$? That is not quite what you have written.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I'm quite sure that's what he meant.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: I'm quite sure that's what the original problem (given to the OP) meant, but I'm trying to get the OP to understand just what is needed.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $Dx$ to $D_x$ since it seems virtually certain that that was intended and since the MathJax coding was so crude that I suspect the original poster would have done it that way if some competence in MathJax had been there. $\qquad$

Comment: This is the original problem: http://imgur.com/0we6Cbe. Was I supposed to write the Dx as D with a subscript x? I thought it was the same thing.

Comment: @user6050977 This is [Euler's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Euler.27s_notation) for derivatives and yes, you need to put the $x$ in subscripts so you don't confuse people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's re-write the equation:

$$x^2y-xy^2+x^2+y^2=0$$

Now, we want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$, so take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$. On the right side, we stick with $0$ because the derivative of $0$ is $0$. On the left side, we want to use addition rule to take the derivative of each term.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y)-\frac{d}{dx}(xy^2)+\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)+\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=0$$

Now, let's do the easier terms first.

- The derivative of $x^2$ with respect to $x$ is $2x$.
- The derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $x$ can be found with chain rule. First, find the derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $y$, which is $2y$. Then, multiply that by the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, or $y'$. Thus, $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=2yy'$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y)-\frac{d}{dx}(xy^2)+2x+2yy'=0$$

Now, let's do $x^2y$ and $xy^2$. We can do break these derivatives up using product rule.

- The derivative of $x^2y$ can be found by looking at $x^2$ and $y$.
- The derivative of $xy^2$ can be found by looking at $x$ and $y^2$.

$$y\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)+x^2\frac{d}{dx}y-\left(y^2\frac{d}{dx}x+x\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)\right)+2x+2yy'=0$$

Now, we can simplify the derivatives:

- $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)$ is clearly $2x$.
- $\frac{d}{dx}y=\frac{dy}{dx}=y'$.
- $\frac{d}{dx}x=\frac{dx}{dx}=1$.
- $\frac{d}{dx}(y^2)=2yy'$ which we figured out above.

$$y2x+x^2y'-\left(y^2(1)+x2yy'\right)+2x+2yy'=0$$

Simplify the left-hand side:

$$2xy+x^2y'-y^2-2xyy'+2x+2yy'=0$$

Separate the $y'$ terms from the not-$y'$ terms and factor out a $y'$.

$$y'(x^2-2xy+2y)-y^2+2xy+2x=0$$

Solve for $y'$:

$$y'=\frac{y^2-2xy-2x}{x^2-2xy+2y}$$

Thus, we are now done.